# Qual é a sintaxe correta para transformar uma variável em Negrito ou em Cores (PHP)?

Tags: php, wordpress, formatação

Na verdade eu não sei nem como perguntar isso corretamente, então tentarei explicar o máximo que puder a minha dúvida...

Eu tenho a seguinte linha de código.

```
<?php echo strval($tour_availability); ?>
```

Essa variável `$tour_availability` recebe uma String que é inserida por um usuário em um text-field comum e impresso na seguinte página abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, o usuário digitou "Disponível" no text-field e a variável `$tour_availability` recebeu a String que juntamente com o comando `echo` apresenta na tela conforme a imagem.

Minha Dúvida!

1- Não encontro a sintaxe correta para mostrar o "Disponível" em negrito ou em cores, por exemplo: Disponível em verde e Indisponível em vermelho.

Já pesquisei comandos como `<b> </b>` e `<strong> </strong>`  mas não consegui aplicar...

Tentei comandos desse tipo `$tour_availability = str_replace(<b>$tour_availability</b>);` Mas sinceramente não consigo a sintaxe correta.

Se fosse apenas texto os comandos  e  funcionam, mas como é variável não estou conseguindo.

Se puderem me ajudar eu agradeço!

Comment: E por que não faz o mais simples que é `<b><?= $tour_availability ?></b>`?

Comment: Anderson, muito obrigado haha.
Funcionou direitinho... Utilizei a função para converter para String já que o campo só aceitava Int e nem me liguei que poderia fazer assim...
Obrigado!

Comment: E se bobear é caso pra CSS mesmo, dependendo de como é gerado esse HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes meter $tour_availability entre uma tag `<b>` para dar só o bold:

```
$tour_availability = '<b>'.$tour_availability.'</b>'
```

Para mudar as cores e outras categorias convém meteres dentro de um `<span>`:7

```
$tour_availability = '<span style="font-weight:bold; color: red;">'.$tour_availability.'</span>'
```